# How to fix Datatables dropdown filter click twice to open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, materialize

I found this very helpful Datatables dropdown multiple filter example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/16/) here on Stackoverflow. The problem is that I should click twice to open dropdown filter.
Is there any one to help me to fix this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       dom: 'lrtip',
        initComplete: function () {
          this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            // console.log(column);
            var select = $("#officeFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
           this.api().columns([3]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            // console.log(column);
            var select = $("#ageFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
          $("#officeFltr,#ageFltr").material_select();
       }
    });
    
    $('#officeFltr').on('change', function(){
     var search = [];
      
      $.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function(){
        search.push($(this).val());
      });
      
      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(2).search(search, true, false).draw();  
    });
    
    $('#ageFltr').on('change', function(){
     var search = [];
      
      $.each($('#ageFltr option:selected'), function(){
        search.push($(this).val());
      });
      
      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(3).search(search, true, false).draw();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-3 hoverable">
      <div class="card-title">
           <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
             <div class="col s12 m4">
               <h5>Summary</h5>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m3 right-align">
               <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" multiple="true">Office:                </span>
               <select multiple="true" id="officeFltr">
               </select>
             </div>
             <div class="col s6 m3">
               <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;">Age:</span>
               <select id="ageFltr" multiple="true"></select>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <div class="summTblDiv">
              <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                          <td>System Architect</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2011/04/25</td>
                          <td>$320,800</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                          <td>Accountant</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2011/07/25</td>
                          <td>$170,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>66</td>
                          <td>2009/01/12</td>
                          <td>$86,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2012/10/13</td>
                          <td>$132,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Dai Rios</td>
                          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>35</td>
                          <td>2012/09/26</td>
                          <td>$217,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                          <td>Development Lead</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2011/09/03</td>
                          <td>$345,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>40</td>
                          <td>2009/06/25</td>
                          <td>$675,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2011/12/12</td>
                          <td>$106,450</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                          <td>Sidney</td>
                          <td>23</td>
                          <td>2010/09/20</td>
                          <td>$85,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/10/09</td>
                          <td>$1,200,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>42</td>
                          <td>2010/12/22</td>
                          <td>$92,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2010/11/14</td>
                          <td>$357,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2011/06/07</td>
                          <td>$206,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Fiona Green</td>
                          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>48</td>
                          <td>2010/03/11</td>
                          <td>$850,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Shou Itou</td>
                          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>20</td>
                          <td>2011/08/14</td>
                          <td>$163,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michelle House</td>
                          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                          <td>Sidney</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2011/06/02</td>
                          <td>$95,400</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Suki Burks</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>53</td>
                          <td>2009/10/22</td>
                          <td>$114,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                          <td>Technical Author</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/05/07</td>
                          <td>$145,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                          <td>Team Leader</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>22</td>
                          <td>2008/10/26</td>
                          <td>$235,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>46</td>
                          <td>2011/03/09</td>
                          <td>$324,050</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Unity Butler</td>
                          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/12/09</td>
                          <td>$85,675</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>51</td>
                          <td>2008/12/16</td>
                          <td>$164,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                          <td>Secretary</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2010/02/12</td>
                          <td>$109,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                          <td>Financial Controller</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>62</td>
                          <td>2009/02/14</td>
                          <td>$452,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2008/12/11</td>
                          <td>$136,200</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                          <td>Director</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>65</td>
                          <td>2008/09/26</td>
                          <td>$645,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2011/02/03</td>
                          <td>$234,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>38</td>
                          <td>2011/05/03</td>
                          <td>$163,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2009/08/19</td>
                          <td>$139,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Thor Walton</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2013/08/11</td>
                          <td>$98,540</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/07/07</td>
                          <td>$87,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2012/04/09</td>
                          <td>$138,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2010/01/04</td>
                          <td>$125,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>56</td>
                          <td>2012/06/01</td>
                          <td>$115,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>43</td>
                          <td>2013/02/01</td>
                          <td>$75,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>46</td>
                          <td>2011/12/06</td>
                          <td>$145,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2011/03/21</td>
                          <td>$356,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Lael Greer</td>
                          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2009/02/27</td>
                          <td>$103,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2010/07/14</td>
                          <td>$86,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Shad Decker</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>51</td>
                          <td>2008/11/13</td>
                          <td>$183,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>29</td>
                          <td>2011/06/27</td>
                          <td>$183,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Donna Snider</td>
                          <td>Customer Support</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/01/25</td>
                          <td>$112,000</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You obviously have code as you have provided a fiddle link, please do not ignore the rules of SO - links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to the latest version of materialize and then use `formSelect` it works

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

$("#officeFltr,#ageFltr").formSelect();
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       dom: 'lrtip',
        initComplete: function () {
          this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            // console.log(column);
            var select = $("#officeFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
           this.api().columns([3]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            // console.log(column);
            var select = $("#ageFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );
          $("#officeFltr,#ageFltr").formSelect();
       }
    });
    
    $('#officeFltr').on('change', function(){
     var search = [];
      
      $.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function(){
        search.push($(this).val());
      });
      
      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(2).search(search, true, false).draw();  
    });
    
    $('#ageFltr').on('change', function(){
     var search = [];
      
      $.each($('#ageFltr option:selected'), function(){
        search.push($(this).val());
      });
      
      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(3).search(search, true, false).draw();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-3 hoverable">
      <div class="card-title">
           <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
             <div class="col s12 m4">
               <h5>Summary</h5>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m3 right-align">
               <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" multiple="true">Office:                </span>
               <select multiple="true" id="officeFltr">
               </select>
             </div>
             <div class="col s6 m3">
               <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;">Age:</span>
               <select id="ageFltr" multiple="true"></select>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <div class="summTblDiv">
              <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                          <td>System Architect</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2011/04/25</td>
                          <td>$320,800</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                          <td>Accountant</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2011/07/25</td>
                          <td>$170,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>66</td>
                          <td>2009/01/12</td>
                          <td>$86,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2012/10/13</td>
                          <td>$132,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Dai Rios</td>
                          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>35</td>
                          <td>2012/09/26</td>
                          <td>$217,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                          <td>Development Lead</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2011/09/03</td>
                          <td>$345,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>40</td>
                          <td>2009/06/25</td>
                          <td>$675,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2011/12/12</td>
                          <td>$106,450</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                          <td>Sidney</td>
                          <td>23</td>
                          <td>2010/09/20</td>
                          <td>$85,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/10/09</td>
                          <td>$1,200,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>42</td>
                          <td>2010/12/22</td>
                          <td>$92,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2010/11/14</td>
                          <td>$357,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2011/06/07</td>
                          <td>$206,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Fiona Green</td>
                          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>48</td>
                          <td>2010/03/11</td>
                          <td>$850,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Shou Itou</td>
                          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>20</td>
                          <td>2011/08/14</td>
                          <td>$163,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michelle House</td>
                          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                          <td>Sidney</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2011/06/02</td>
                          <td>$95,400</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Suki Burks</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>53</td>
                          <td>2009/10/22</td>
                          <td>$114,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                          <td>Technical Author</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/05/07</td>
                          <td>$145,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                          <td>Team Leader</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>22</td>
                          <td>2008/10/26</td>
                          <td>$235,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>46</td>
                          <td>2011/03/09</td>
                          <td>$324,050</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Unity Butler</td>
                          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/12/09</td>
                          <td>$85,675</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>51</td>
                          <td>2008/12/16</td>
                          <td>$164,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                          <td>Secretary</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2010/02/12</td>
                          <td>$109,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                          <td>Financial Controller</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>62</td>
                          <td>2009/02/14</td>
                          <td>$452,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2008/12/11</td>
                          <td>$136,200</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                          <td>Director</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>65</td>
                          <td>2008/09/26</td>
                          <td>$645,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2011/02/03</td>
                          <td>$234,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>38</td>
                          <td>2011/05/03</td>
                          <td>$163,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Tokyo</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2009/08/19</td>
                          <td>$139,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Thor Walton</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2013/08/11</td>
                          <td>$98,540</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/07/07</td>
                          <td>$87,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2012/04/09</td>
                          <td>$138,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2010/01/04</td>
                          <td>$125,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>56</td>
                          <td>2012/06/01</td>
                          <td>$115,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>43</td>
                          <td>2013/02/01</td>
                          <td>$75,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>46</td>
                          <td>2011/12/06</td>
                          <td>$145,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2011/03/21</td>
                          <td>$356,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Lael Greer</td>
                          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                          <td>London</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2009/02/27</td>
                          <td>$103,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2010/07/14</td>
                          <td>$86,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Shad Decker</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh</td>
                          <td>51</td>
                          <td>2008/11/13</td>
                          <td>$183,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Singapore</td>
                          <td>29</td>
                          <td>2011/06/27</td>
                          <td>$183,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Donna Snider</td>
                          <td>Customer Support</td>
                          <td>New York</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/01/25</td>
                          <td>$112,000</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works.

Comment: Sure, I accepted your answer.